# Unable to get rid of 'Access Denied' error on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file uploader hosted on an s3 bucket that works fine. I need to use that form to upload to another bucket (hosted by me). I can access the second bucket with an URL (both are public). For the second bucket the policy is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also added a CORS policy. When I try to upload a text file using the form in the first bucket, I get an access denied error.

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://gwexpertsxmluploader.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://gwexpertsxmluploader.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server has moved to https. You use http. So try:

```
https://gwexpertsv7sourcebucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?filename=
```

Comment: Thanks, but the published URL (by Amazon) is in http.